# Как динамически добавлять radioButton в recycleView?

Tags: android, recycleview

Планирую добавить кнопку в bar, по нажатию которой, можно было бы добавить radioButton в элементы recycleView.

Как можно это сделать? Куда смотреть, где искать?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно для всех видимых ViewHolder сделать видимыми (или добавить) radioButtons

```
        int count = mRecyclerView.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            YouViewHolder holder = (YouViewHolder) mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(mRecyclerView.getChildAt(i));
            //Set visiblity for radioButtons
        }
```

А далее если нужно и у остальных включать радиобатоны при прокрутки, то в адаптере храним флаг сигнализирующий включать radioButtons или нет. И в зависимости от флага в onBindViewHolder() так же включаем radioButtons или же прячем.